# Fantasy book series, a young boy finds a book which contains a passage in it that when read gives him like magical powers

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I read these books years ago but never got to finish them. I am trying to figure out the name of the books but cannot remember at all. I will try to describe them as detailed as possible but it has been years and some information might be a little off. I read these in middle school if that helps. The series was probably 8+ books.

The first few books are about a young kid that somehow finds a mysterious book that contains a like magical passage that when read gives the reader of this passage access to like the magical world. He eventually finds other people like him and practices with them. A specific scene that i remember is that after school him and one of his female friends that happened to also have some magical powers go to the forest, cast some sort of spell that makes it so that people can't see whats going on in the area the spell is cast on. This way they can go about doing magic and practicing without having to worry about other people seeing what they were doing.

Later on in the books his little sister finds the book and reads the passage by accident. She also gets powers and (I believe it affects everyone a little different because her magical powers were different) she was given a mind kind of like a computer and was able to process information really fast. There's a part in the book where she is communicating via typing things out because she could do it way faster than speaking to her.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Could be the [Young Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Wizards) series by Diane Duane.

Answer (score 7):

This could be the [Young Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Wizards) series by Diane Duane.  The first book came out in 1983, the eighth in 2005, and the most recent (11th) in 2016. [Not sure when you were in middle school.]  They are considered young adult novels.

In the first book, [So You Want to Be a Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Wizard) a young girl (Nita) finds a library book that does contain an oath, which upon speaking, makes someone a wizard.  She does later meet a boy (Kit) who also has found a book.  They do have a private area they use at first to practice in.  Another characters of note is Fred, the white hole they accidentally summon who sometimes "burps" out random objects...like cars or planes.  They do end up travelling to an alternate dimension where they have to deal with cars that hunt each other, but end up befriending one.

The third book [High Wizardry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Wizardry) deals a lot with Nita's younger sister who gets her own wizard's manual in the form of a computer.  She ends up creating a race of computers on a new world and does become somewhat computer-like herself.

Later books bring in Kit's sister, who is not a wizard but is different due to her association with wizards.

Comment: If so, it will be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89289/book-about-a-boy-who-travels-to-a-parallel-universe-to-get-a-book/89297#89297

Comment: Also, part of High Wizardry involves the sister linking her mind to a giant computer. This is almost certainly the series you're looking for.