# I'm looking for a science fiction/fantasy that I got into many years ago

Tags: story-identification

All I remember are details of the plot. A wizard helps a neighbor set up a new computer. The neighbor's son goes on the computer and finds out it's magic and can transport him between worlds. The boy's older sister chases after him from world to world.

Comment: possibly related to as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89289/book-about-a-boy-who-travels-to-a-parallel-universe-to-get-a-book (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 9):

### [High Wizardry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Wizardry) by Diane Duane.

The younger sibling is a girl. her sister is already a wizard , and when a new laptop is delivered it is set up to teach wizardry. The younger girl first goes to Mars, and ends up at the far side of the universe. The book is #3 in the [Young Wizards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Wizards) series.

[image]

Comment: Diane Duane - one of my favorite authors.