Sci-Fi Book with a girl who travels through space with a laptop
I believe this is either a YA or children's book cause I read it when I was probably late elementary.
I don't remember a ton but I remember there was a girl who would write different commands into a laptop and travel to other planets like Mars. I think she ended up getting stranded on some planet at some point in the story because her laptop stops working.
If I also remember correctly I think there was more than 1 POV in the story.

When exactly did you read this? We don't know when you were in "late elementary". Why does the laptop stops working? Does it run out of battery or get a virus or is it simply dropped and broken in that manner?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Could be Diane Duane's High Wizardry, third in her Young Wizards series.
In it, Dairine, the younger sister of Nita, one of the protagonists of the first two books, is given a computer and manages to somehow load a copy of the instruction manual for wizards onto it, allowing her to cast spells. Some of which allows her to travel to other worlds. Nita and fellow wizard Kit have to find her before too much harm is done.

Duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89289/book-about-a-boy-who-travels-to-a-parallel-universe-to-get-a-book and several others

High Wizardry by Diane Duane. It's the third book in the Young Wizards series. She gets a laptop with the Wizard's Manual downloaded onto it. Her first trip is to Mars, then to an intergalactic travel hub, but she ends up on a silicon planet; where she kickstarts the evolution on a race of robotic silicon beings. She is being chased all the time by the "Lone One", a wizard's version of the Devil. The laptop is supposed to be an Apple brand, but the logo doesn't have the bite taken out of it.

A hair too slow! :)

Oh my god the mention of an apple laptop with no bite opened a core memory of this book, im so happy you guys could help me find it

Just in case it isn't High Wizardry, could it be George's Secret Key to the Universe by Lucy and Stephen Hawking in 2007?
They have a computer which creates doors to other planets and moons.  There's a joke bit in there that went something along the lines of, "How do you get the computer to open one of the doors?  By pressing the 'space' key of course."  I think one of the books in the series saw them being pursued by a nemesis (maybe a rival scientist?) who interferes with the computer and leaves them stranded on another planet.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do any of the other points match?  Do they go to Mars?  Is it a laptop?  Does it stop working?

Mars is mentioned, and there is a picture of Mars and its moons.  I'm fuzzy on the details, because I read this book 17 years ago.  I don't remember if their computer is a laptop.  I think there's a point at which the antagonist interferes with the computer to strand the protagonists, but I don't remember if that means that the computer stopped working.
